# Preventing Safari from prompting when trying to open a native app in ipad

Tags: safari, dialog, prompt

I am trying to open a third party barcode scanner (pic2shop) from a web application in safari browser(ipad), first time around the scanner app opens without any prompts, but second time onwards safari displays a promt asking "Open this in 'pic2shop' application" with an 'OK' and 'Cancel' button. How can I prevent this from happening, is there any way?

Comment: I'm looking for the same fix. Did you figure it out?
Or, how to handle the Cancel action - that does not open the app once you click cancel.

Comment: @mircaea I am trying to handle cancel action too. Did you figure it out?